# How to Enable MTLS with MultiCluster Service on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, mtls, google-anthos-service-mesh

I am looking for how to enable mTLS with services exported via the ServiceExport resource. I currently have two clusters in a fleet and i would like to establish multicluster service communication with mTLS. I have an istio mTLS `STRICT` policy applied on a namespace in cluster 1

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: mcs-mtls-policy
  namespace: multi-cluster-demo
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

However when i try to reach the service from a pod cluster 2, i get the following response:

```
root@mcs-test:/# curl whereami.multi-cluster-demo.svc.clusterset.local -vk
*   Trying 10.32.24.79:80...
* Connected to whereami.multi-cluster-demo.svc.clusterset.local (10.32.24.79) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: whereami.multi-cluster-demo.svc.clusterset.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
< content-length: 95
< content-type: text/plain
< date: Tue, 08 Aug 2023 09:50:07 GMT
< server: envoy
< 
* Connection #0 to host whereami.multi-cluster-demo.svc.clusterset.local left intact
```

If i change the mTLS policy mode to `PERMISSIVE` i get a successful response however, i would like to enforce mTLS within the cluster.

```
   Trying 10.32.24.79:80...
* Connected to whereami.multi-cluster-demo.svc.clusterset.local (10.32.24.79) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: whereami.multi-cluster-demo.svc.clusterset.local
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< server: envoy
< date: Tue, 08 Aug 2023 11:06:25 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 390
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 5
<
```

I am assuming this is due to the traffic being sent without mTLS but even when i try to do it manually as described [here](https://istio.io/v0.5/docs/tasks/security/mutual-tls.html), it doesn't work as well. Could this be due to Anthos? or is it related to Traffic Director? I know traffic director supports mTLS but i'm not sure of how to configure that with ServiceExport resource.

Please help guide me, thanks.

Comment: Are you using OSS istio or ASM ? Do you have Istio deployed in both clusters ?

Comment: I am using ASM and both clusters are in the same fleet @boredabdel

Comment: It should work if you are using Mesh or Istio CA https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/v1.16/docs/unified-install/gke-install-multi-cluster

Do you follow this guide ?